# Is there any method to figure out if a random variable has a sine oscillation pattern?

Tags: statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, pattern-recognition

I have a random variable and wondering if there's a mathematical test to see if it has an oscillation pattern like a sine wave.

Data is a time series collected every day and follows a random walk. Presumably, there's no pattern as autocorrelation shows no correlation between different lags.

Is it possible to run a test and get the probability of this variable having a sine pattern and what would be the base value for that?

Comment: By "random variable" presumably you mean some kind of sequence of data.  You need to tell us more about it: how often and regularly you collect the values, their scale of measurement, and what role randomness might play in your modeling and understanding of those data.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried to re-phrase my question with more detail on the data. However, I don't expect a specific solution, more or less looking for a clue on how should I approach it.

Comment: What's wrong with plotting it?

Comment: You could perform a smooth and examine the frequency data.

Comment: a simple thing like plotting the frequency of occurrences of different values may help. a sine wave will have the most density around its min and max, and the lowest density in the middle, for instance

Comment: It's not much of an answer, which is why this is a comment, but I am puzzled at why you would ever try fitting a sine unless you knew in principle and could see from a line plot that it was a natural model.

Comment: @NickCox I'm entertaining the idea that combining polynomial and sine functions can better fit the trend. Does that make sense?

Comment: It could make sense but it is not what you are asking and there is no information in the question to say what might or should work well. 2018 question is still alive?

Answer (score 2):

A sinusoidal has in its autocorrelation evenly spaced maxima because at every period they match perfectly. If there is a periodicity in your data, you should be able to see evenly spaced peaks in the autocorrelation function.

However, this will not result in a probability of having a sine. This would be difficult anyway if you don't fix the frequency of a sine. For a fixed frequency and phase you could calculate the cross-correlation coefficient between a sinusoid and the signal.

Comment: Thank you Nick! Is there any reference for how to calculate this cross-correlation coefficient? Is there a widely accepted threshold for this coefficient to make judgment on sinusoidal pattern?